# How to find and combine the Whole Chemical Compound string using regex within a LaTex

Tags: python, regex, nlp, python-re

For the string below:

```
Which one of following pairs of gases is the major cause of greenhouse effect?
A. \( C O_{2} \) and \( O_{3} \)
в. \( C O_{2} \) and \( C O \)
c. \( C F C \) and \( S O_{2} \)
D. \( C O_{2} \) and \( N_{2} O \)
```

I want something like:

```
Which one of following pairs of gases is the major cause of greenhouse effect?
A. \( CO2 \) and \( O3 \)
в. \( CO2 \) and \( CO \)
c. \( CFC \) and \( SO2 \)
D. \( CO2 \) and \( N2O \)
```

I used `re.sub('[A-Z]_{[0-9]}', '<CHEM>', text)` as an experiment so that I could combine the two. How could I combine the whole equation together? Each element is separated by a space and each element could be capitl letters and/or made of 1 or more alphabets. It could be something like:

`\( Na Cl_{2} \) and \( Fe k_{3} cl  \)` -> `\( NaCl2 \) and \( Fek3cl  \)`

Comment: What about CH4 ?

Comment: `C11H15NO2` is the answer!

Comment: IMO, You took a little too much C20H25N3O to say this kind of things.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, what about it, other than it's a colourless, odourless gas that occurs abundantly in nature, the simplest member of the paraffin series of hydrocarbons that is among the most potent of the greenhouse gases?

Comment: @CarySwoveland but its step father is sh!!t, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can use capture groups with re.sub:

```python
re.sub(r'([A-Z][a-z]?)(_{([0-9]+)})? *', r'\1\3', text)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBLTsMwEN37FKNsYgOpgGxggaIKhFjBgkUlkqgy6SQ2Sm1r7IpP1UtxEm4U7AqVVRcjzfvMk964z6CsKa8cTXrtLAUgZCzgR4AbaBhlWcYWSncKrEGwPfR2HO27NgM4qcknapAePWgPQSGs5Zsl6OTG7@0DIRplE8K@xy5UbD6DhsMtPC23lztoBEizSkzEZcLs5/uIIzJJ7/7k@zj/4vPBzu6O3D/uccoAlopJ41PLiXDmN6@ccl7Pi5e2lsVXWwm@3PL6vLhuT8VOVHCSnwHlzUVTxiU9SEyOtAk8pojpAeNbYGFpXP0C)

If you want to preserve the whitespace after the last element, you can use

```python
re.sub(r'([A-Z][a-z]?)(_{([0-9]+)})?( *(?=[A-Z]))?', r'\1\3', text)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBLTsMwEN37FKNsYgOpoNnAoooqEGIFCxaVSKLKpJPYKLWjsSs@VS/FSXqjYEcIVl2MNO8zT3ozfHplTX490Ki3gyUPhIx5/PCwgIpRkiRspXSjwBoE20Jr@96@a9PBIDW5SHXSoQPtwCuErXyzBI3cucneEaJRNiJsW2x8wZYzqDjcwtN6Pz9AJUCaTWQCziNmx@8TjsBEvfmV78P8i89/dnZ34v5xwjEDWCwmjYstR8KZ271ySnm5zF7qUmZfdSH4es/Ly@ymPhcHUXA448Vi0oUo0gugtLqq8rDEZ4lxIG08D4lifMDwIlhZ6jc/)

### Explanation:

```python
([A-Z][a-z]?)(_{([0-9]+)})? *
([A-Z][a-z]?)                             # Matches chemical names. Captures the name of the chemical in group 1.
             (_{([0-9]+)})?               # Matches a potential subscript. Captures the number in group 3.
                            *             # Matches trailing whitespace. This causes it to be removed
                           ( *(?=[A-Z]))? # Alternatively, match the whitespace, only if it's followed by a capital letter. This means that it will be removed only if it's followed by a chemical element.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may write

```
rgx = r'(?<!\\\()[ _{}](?=[ A-Z\d _{}]* \\\))'
```

```
re.sub(rgx, '', str)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o0W6Y7/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<!            # begin a negative lookbehind
  \\\(          # match '\('          
)               # end negative lookbehind
[ _{}]          # match a character in the char class
(?=             # begin a positive lookahead
  [ A-Z\d _{}]* # match zero or more characters in the char class
  [ ]\\\)       # match ' \)'
)               # end positive lookahead
```

I've put the space character in a character class (`[ ]`) merely to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import re
text = r"\( Na Cl_{2} \) and \( Fe k_{3} cl  \)"
print( re.sub(r'\\\(\s*([^()]*?)\s*\\\)', lambda x: f'\\( {"".join(c if c.isalnum() else "" for c in x.group(1))} \\)', text) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QKYOeH), see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JIpJp9/1). *Details*:

- `\\` - a `\` char
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^()]*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `)`, `(`
- `\s*\\\)` - zero or more whitespaces, and then a `\)` string.

The `lambda x: f'\\( {"".join(c if c.isalnum() else "" for c in x.group(1))} \\)'` replacement replaces the match with `\(` , Group 1 with all non-alphanumeric chars removed and  `\)`.